# Vertical secondary pointing menu in semantic ui: How to bind to h2 section?

Tags: menu, scroll, semantic-ui

I am porting old code to semantic ui, which is quite nice. I am trying to reproduce the behavior of the vertical side menu they have used in all theirs docs (vertical secondary pointing menu). See for instance the left menu ("Types", "Groups", etc.) on this page:

http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html

A click on a menu item makes the page scroll to the named section, and I can't reproduce this behavior. I don't see any href in the  entries. There is probably something that exceeds my (very classical) HTML/Javascript knowledge. I would like to have a simple example like this work the same way (the 'peek' class basically sticks the menu on the left):

```
<body>      
  <div class="peek">
    <div class="ui vertical pointing secondary menu">
      <a class="item active">Part 1</a>
      <a class="item">Part2</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2 class="ui dividing header">Part 1</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec 
  odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. 
  Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede 
  (etc. put a long enough text here for scrolling).</p>

  <h2 class="ui dividing header">Part 2</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec 
  odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. 
  Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

This does not work if I just include semantic.min.js and semantic.css in my header. So I understand that no default behavior is predefined in this case. Would some good soul be kind enough to help me with the required CSS/Javascript within semantic UI?

Many thanks in advance,

Yvonnick

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to use the same, but since is not in the docs, I just assumed is not included in Semantic and it's a custom class.

What I did was to leave that menu in a different column, and then

```
.peek{
  position:fixed;
}
```